# Is it good to run flush table in MySQL to release open file limit?

Tags: mysql, database, locking, mysql-workbench

We have a problem that our open file limit increase in couple of days and database become slow. So we have to either restart the MySQL service or run FLUSH Tables manually.

So i want to know is it good to flush the tables and how frequent we can do this operation.

And whats the impact if we run it in off hours and in working hours?